# How to consider multiple conditions before replace?

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have several lines were most of them have the formats as below:

- format1 --> "FIELD = VALUE"
- format2 --> "KKF NN MM UZZ123.CODE.TXT"

I'm trying to convert to xml like format with these conditions.

1-) If FIELD = "XYZ" then replace with `<EEE>VALUE</EEE>`

2-) If FIELD = anything else, replace with the same FIELD

3-) If line is like format2 replace with `<DIF>VALUE</DIF>`

The is my current code.

```
import re

data = '''ABC = 300
XYZ = MA2
MMW = TT1
ABC = YU3
ABC = 719
XYZ = 120
KKF NN MM UZZ123.CODE.TXT
KKF NN MM UZZ456.CODE.TXT'''

data.splitlines()
out = []

for line in data.splitlines():    
    out.append(re.sub(r'(.+)\s+=\s(.+)', r'<\1>\2<\1>', line))
    out.append(re.sub(r'XYZ\s+=\s+(.+)', r'<EEE>\1<EEE>', line))
    out.append(re.sub(r'KKF.+UZZ(.+).CODE.+', r'<DIF>\1<DIF>', line))

out
['<ABC>300<ABC>',
 'ABC = 300',
 'ABC = 300',
 '<XYZ>MA2<XYZ>',
 '<EEE>MA2<EEE>',
 'XYZ = MA2',
 '<MMW>TT1<MMW>',
 'MMW = TT1',
 'MMW = TT1',
 '<ABC>YU3<ABC>',
 'ABC = YU3',
 'ABC = YU3',
 '<ABC>719<ABC>',
 'ABC = 719',
 'ABC = 719',
 '<XYZ>120<XYZ>',
 '<EEE>120<EEE>',
 'XYZ = 120',
 'KKF NN MM UZZ123.CODE.TXT',
 'KKF NN MM UZZ123.CODE.TXT',
 '<DIF>123<DIF>',
 'KKF NN MM UZZ456.CODE.TXT',
 'KKF NN MM UZZ456.CODE.TXT',
 '<DIF>456<DIF>']
```

And my desired output would be like this.

```
<ABC>300</ABC>
<EEE>MA2</EEE>
<MMW>TT1</MMW>
<ABC>YU3</ABC>
<ABC>719</ABC>
<EEE>120</EEE>
<DIF>123</DIFF>
<DIF>456</DIFF>
```

How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: 3-) If line is like format2 replace with "VALUE" <- `format2 --> "KKF NN MM UZZ123.CODE.TXT"` has no "VALUE" in it??

Comment: Right.  Once again, this is not a regular expression problem.  It's a text parsing problem.

Comment: @Would be nice if you could share how you would do it without regex, since I think would be faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python's [structural pattern matching](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/) was designed for this exact type of scenario.

```py
data = '''ABC = 300
XYZ = MA2
MMW = TT1
ABC = YU3
ABC = 719
XYZ = 120
KKF NN MM UZZ123.CODE.TXT
KKF NN MM UZZ456.CODE.TXT'''

result = []

for line in data.splitlines():
    match line.split(" "):
        case [field, "=", value]:
            if field == "XYZ":
                field = "EEE"
        case ["KKF", "NN", "MM", text]:
            field = "DIF"
            value = text[3:6]
    result.append(f"<{field}>{value}</{field}>")

output = "\n".join(result)

print(output)
```

This result matches your desired output.

Comment: Thanks for showing a solution without regex

Comment: Not sure why is giving me this error `match line.split(" "):
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: structural pattern matching was introduced in Python 3.10 (which was released in October of 2021). Python 3.9 and earlier doesn't support this syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use named groups for the task:

```py
import re


data = """\
ABC = 300
XYZ = MA2
MMW = TT1
ABC = YU3
ABC = 719
XYZ = 120
KKF NN MM UZZ123.CODE.TXT
KKF NN MM UZZ456.CODE.TXT"""

pat = r"^(?P<key>.+) = (?P<value>.+)|^KKF .+?(?P<num>\d+)\.CODE"
pat = re.compile(pat, flags=re.M)

out = []
for m in pat.finditer(data):
    if (n := m.group("num")) is not None:
        out.append(f"<DIF>{n}</DIF>")
    else:
        k, v = m.group("key"), m.group("value")
        if k == "XYZ":
            out.append(f"<EEE>{v}</EEE>")
        else:
            out.append(f"<{k}>{v}</{k}>")

print("\n".join(out))
```

Prints:

```xml
<ABC>300</ABC>
<EEE>MA2</EEE>
<MMW>TT1</MMW>
<ABC>YU3</ABC>
<ABC>719</ABC>
<EEE>120</EEE>
<DIF>123</DIF>
<DIF>456</DIF>
```